# Is there any way to customize actions type in redux-toolkit createSlice?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

When we create slice we define "name" of slice and then define reducers.

When we use action creators created by this slice we have action type looks like "nameOfSlice/nameOfReducer". But I need my custom concatenation "[nameOfSlice] nameOfReducer".

By now, I use name of slice "[nameOfSlice] " and get "[nameOfSlice] /nameOfReducer".
I don't want this slash.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. RTK is deliberately opinionated, and our standard recommendation is `'domain/eventName'`:

https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#write-action-types-as-domaineventname

As such, `createSlice` does not offer a way to customize that behavior.

You *could* use `createAction` for every individual action, but I would recommend against doing that because `createSlice` simplifies that process considerably.